# Input type file to activescaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activescaffold

My table resources have image field.

Using active_scaffold created the: EDIT DELETE CREATE SHOW pages where shows all fields from database with values.

But on the image field I would like to implement this library:

http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/

So how can I manage to get a custom input type file, and in SHOW to display that image? I tried with file_column gem but no success.

Comment: Please share your code for the image field

Comment: active_scaffold have only generated code. How can I make a input type file for one of the fields?